# Serialize Python dictionary to XML

Tags: python, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

There is simple JSON serialization module with name "simplejson" which easily serializes Python objects to JSON.

I'm looking for similar module which can serialize to XML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/415983/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxser/

http://soapy.sourceforge.net/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-pyth5/

http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/xml_matters_1.txt

Comment: > http://code.activestate.com/recipes/415983/
This one doesn't serialize to XML only to marshal format. And also I don't like sys.exit on Exception.

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxser/
This one is not BSD. Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm looking for python module or BSD, so I can distribute with my BSD software.

The last 2 - for webservices, I'm looking for regular XML serializator.

Comment: zdmytriv: you can distribute a LGPL library with your BSD code without liabilities.

Comment: @nosklo: I didn't know that you can do that. Now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

There is [`huTools.structured.dict2xml`](https://github.com/hudora/huTools/blob/master/huTools/structured.py#L171) which tries to be compatible to `simplejson` in spirit. You can give it hints how to wrap nested sub-structures. Check the documentation for [`huTools.structured.dict2et`](https://github.com/hudora/huTools/blob/master/huTools/structured.py#L99) which returns `ElementTree` Objects instead if the strings returned by `dict2xml`.

```
>>> data = {"kommiauftragsnr":2103839, "anliefertermin":"2009-11-25", "prioritaet": 7,
... "ort": u"Hücksenwagen",
... "positionen": [{"menge": 12, "artnr": "14640/XL", "posnr": 1},],
... "versandeinweisungen": [{"guid": "2103839-XalE", "bezeichner": "avisierung48h",
...                          "anweisung": "48h vor Anlieferung unter 0900-LOGISTIK avisieren"},
... ]}

>>> print ET.tostring(dict2et(data, 'kommiauftrag',
... listnames={'positionen': 'position', 'versandeinweisungen': 'versandeinweisung'}))
'''<kommiauftrag>
<anliefertermin>2009-11-25</anliefertermin>
<positionen>
    <position>
        <posnr>1</posnr>
        <menge>12</menge>
        <artnr>14640/XL</artnr>
    </position>
</positionen>
<ort>H&#xC3;&#xBC;cksenwagen</ort>
<versandeinweisungen>
    <versandeinweisung>
        <bezeichner>avisierung48h</bezeichner>
        <anweisung>48h vor Anlieferung unter 0900-LOGISTIK avisieren</anweisung>
        <guid>2103839-XalE</guid>
    </versandeinweisung>
</versandeinweisungen>
<prioritaet>7</prioritaet>
<kommiauftragsnr>2103839</kommiauftragsnr>
</kommiauftrag>'''
```

Comment: huTools is not compatible with Python 3 (```'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'```).

Comment: What are the licensing terms of this thing? Can I use it my commercial app?

Answer (score 12):

try this one. only problem I don't use attributes (because i dont like them)
[dict2xml on pynuggets.wordpress.com](http://pynuggets.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/dict2xml-4/) 
[dict2xml on activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577739-dict2xml/)

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import copy

class dict2xml(object):
    doc     = Document()

    def __init__(self, structure):
        if len(structure) == 1:
            rootName    = str(structure.keys()[0])
            self.root   = self.doc.createElement(rootName)

            self.doc.appendChild(self.root)
            self.build(self.root, structure[rootName])

    def build(self, father, structure):
        if type(structure) == dict:
            for k in structure:
                tag = self.doc.createElement(k)
                father.appendChild(tag)
                self.build(tag, structure[k])

        elif type(structure) == list:
            grandFather = father.parentNode
            tagName     = father.tagName
            grandFather.removeChild(father)
            for l in structure:
                tag = self.doc.createElement(tagName)
                self.build(tag, l)
                grandFather.appendChild(tag)

        else:
            data    = str(structure)
            tag     = self.doc.createTextNode(data)
            father.appendChild(tag)

    def display(self):
        print self.doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = {'auftrag':{"kommiauftragsnr":2103839, "anliefertermin":"2009-11-25", "prioritaet": 7,"ort": u"Huecksenwagen","positionen": [{"menge": 12, "artnr": "14640/XL", "posnr": 1},],"versandeinweisungen": [{"guid": "2103839-XalE", "bezeichner": "avisierung48h","anweisung": "48h vor Anlieferung unter 0900-LOGISTIK avisieren"},]}}
    xml = dict2xml(example)
    xml.display()
```

Comment: Here is some problem with creating another instance of dict2xml `xml.dom.HierarchyRequestErr: two document elements disallowed`,  
so I added unlink method:
`def unlink(self):
    self.doc.unlink()`

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a simple function that serializes dictionaries to xml (under 30 lines).

Usage:

```
mydict = {
    'name': 'The Andersson\'s',
    'size': 4,
    'children': {
        'total-age': 62,
        'child': [
            {
                'name': 'Tom',
                'sex': 'male',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Betty',
                'sex': 'female',
            }
        ]
    },
}
print(dict2xml(mydict, 'family'))
```

Result:

```
<family name="The Andersson's" size="4">
        <children total-age="62">
                <child name="Tom" sex="male"/>
                <child name="Betty" sex="female"/>
        </children>
</family>
```

The full source (including an example) can be found on https://gist.github.com/reimund/5435343/

**Note:** This function will serialize dictionary entries as attributes rather than text nodes. Modifying it to support text would be very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Most objects in Python are represented as dicts underneath:

```
>>> class Fred(object) : 
...    def __init__(self, n) : self.n = n 
... 
>>> a = Fred(100)
>>> print a.__dict__ 
{'n': 100}
```

So this is similar to asking how to convert dicts to XML.
There are tools for converting dict to/from XML at:

http://www.picklingtools.com

Here is a simple example:

```
    >>> import xmltools

    >>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2.2, 'c':'three' }
    >>> xx = xmltools.WriteToXMLString(d)
    >>> print xx
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <top>
      <a>1</a>
      <b>2.2</b>
      <c>three</c>
    </top>
```

There is a lot of documentation at the web site showing examples:

[XML Tools Manual](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/xmldoc.html)

It is difficult to convert "exactly" between dicts and XML: What is a list? What do you do with attributes?  How do you handle numeric keys?  A lot of these issues have been addressed
and are discussed in the XML tools documentation (above).

Does speed matter to you?  Or does ease of use matter?
There is a pure C++ module (all written in C++), a pure Python module (all written in Python), and a Python C Extension module (written in C++, but wrapped so Python can call it).  The C++ and the Python C Extension module are orders of magnitude faster, but of course require compiling to get going.  The Python module should just work, but is slower: