# Writing XML from Python : Python equivalent of .NET XmlTextWriter?

Tags: python, xml, ironpython, jython

I have some IronPython code which makes use of XmlTextWriter which allows me to write code like

```
self.writer = System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(filename, None)
self.writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
self.writer.WriteStartElement(name)
self.writer.WriteString(str(text))
self.writer.WriteEndElement()

...

self.writer.Close()
```

I would like to make my code portable across Python implementations (CPython, IronPython and Jython).  Is there a streaming Python XML writer I can use for this without needing to use either print statements, or to construct a whole DOM tree before writing it out to file?

Comment: Is this the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019895/serialize-python-dictionary-to-xml

Comment: @S.Lott No it isn't. The question you refer to is about serialising Python data structures directly to XML. This question is about producing a specific XML form from Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a module named loxun to do just that: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/loxun/. It runs with CPython 2.5 and Jython 2.5, but I never tried it with IronPython.

Example usage:

```
with open("...", "wb") as out:
  xml = XmlWriter(out)
  xml.addNamespace("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
  xml.startTag("xhtml:html")
  xml.startTag("xhtml:body")
  xml.text("Hello world!")
  xml.tag("xhtml:img", {"src": "smile.png", "alt": ":-)"})
  xml.endTag()
  xml.endTag()
  xml.close()
```

And the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xhtml:html xlmns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xhtml:body>
    Hello world!
    <xhtml:img alt=":-)" src="smile.png" />
  </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

Among other features, it detects missalligned tags while you write, uses a streaming API with a small memory footprint, supports Unicode and allows to disable pretty printing.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the .NET implementation you're talking about, but it sounds like the closest you're going to get is Python's [SAX parser](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) (specifically, the [XMLGenerator class](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator) -- some sample code [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/03/12/py-xml.html)).

Comment: Specifically, xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator, which is part of sax but not really a parser.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tool to facilitate XML generation from Python ([code](http://github.com/billzeller/xmlegant-for-python/tree/master) and [tutorial](http://www.from.bz/2009/03/28/announcing-xmlegant-for-python/))

Comment: "I a tool"? What does that mean? ;)

Comment: Most elegant.  Can you provide an example of how this would be used in the case where I don't know the element names until run time?

Comment: It assumes the element names are known so it sounds like it doesn't solve your problem. (Well, you could write something like
    x = XMLegant()
    element_name = "root"
    el = getattr(x, element_name)
but that seems to defeat the point.)