# Python: Add subelement to an element based on value of a sibling subelement?

Tags: python, xml

Lots of python XML parsing tutorials out there, but not that many on updating XML, and none I can find that match my needs.  Sorry for the N00B.

I have a need to add subelements to a particular element based on the value of another subelement.

```
<CadData>
   <FireIncidentCollection>
      <FireIncident>
         <IncidentNo>12345</IncidentNo>
         <ApparatusCollection>
            <Apparatus>
               <Unit>E29</Unit>
            </Apparatus>
            <Apparatus>
               <Unit>TW29</Unit>
            </Apparatus>
            <Apparatus>
               <Unit>R29</Unit>
            </Apparatus>
         </ApparatusCollection>
      </FireIncident>
   </FireIncidentCollection>
</CadData>
```

I have values and even other subtrees I need to add based on the "Unit" value of an "Apparatus" element.  For example, I may need to add this snippet in that "Apparatus" element when the "Unit"=="TW29":

```
<DispatchTime>20221115T06:05:04-6.00</DispatchTime>
<ApparatusPersonnelCollection>
  <ApparatusPersonnel>
     <ID>23456</ID>
  </ApparatusPersonnel>
  <ApparatusPersonnel>
    <ID>78901</ID>
</ApparatusPersonnelCollection>
```

So far I'm resisting the urge to dump everything to a DB and re-writing the whole file each time :).  I'm sure there's a way in ElementTree or DOM, but I can't figure it out (not for lack of effort).  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
(Oh, and no, I don't control the schema- I just have to adhere to it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to put this information into a dictionary - then it will be much easier to update your data

I'd recommend using [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) library with [a mixture of this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-xml-to-dictionary/) - which will allow you to convert to a dictionary that you can traverse.

From there, just traverse down the dictionary. The nice thing about the `xmltodict` library is that it will convert xml with the same tag into a list, so your `ApparatusCollection` might look something like this once it's converted:

```
>>> data['CadData']['FireIncidentCollection']['FireIncident']['ApparatusCollection']
{'Apparatus': [{'Unit': 'E29'}, {'Unit': 'TW29'}, {'Unit': 'R29'}]}
```

Just find the "ApparatusCollect" key, and update the "Apparatus" section. My guess is that it would look close to this:

```
{'Apparatus': [
  {
   'Unit': 'E29', 
   'DispatchTime':20221115T06:05:04-6.00},
   'ApparatusPersonnelCollection': {
     'ApparatusPersonnel': [23456, 78901]
   } ...
```

After you've added what you need, just convert the [dictionary back into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021526/converting-an-array-dict-to-xml-in-python).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Zach!  I'll investigate that method.  I really appreciate the advice!

Comment: No prob @buckyswider ! if it ends up helping you, definitely accept the answer! I'll also check it a bit later today to see if I can refine it

Comment: Oh well, it was a good idea!  Unfortunately "xmltodict" and "dicttoxml" are not the exact inverse of one another.  The latter adds extra levels for "item" members and groups the individual element tags into a parent node.  To relate to my example above:  Instead of having multiple sets of <Apparatus></Apparatus> entries, it produces  <Apparatus><Item></Item><Item></Item><Item></Item> </Apparatus>.   So close and yet so far!

Comment: OK, I got it!  Instead of "dicttoxml" to restore the xml, 'xmltodict' has a built-in "unparse" method.  Using that got me back where I started.  Thanks Zach!