# Convert JSON to XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, json

I see a number of questions on SO asking about ways to convert XML to JSON, but I'm interested in going the other way. Is there a python library for converting JSON to XML?

---

**Edit:** Nothing came back right away, so I went ahead and wrote a script that solves this problem.

Python already allows you to convert from JSON into a native dict (using `json` or, in versions < 2.6, `simplejson`), so I wrote a library that converts native dicts into an XML string.

https://github.com/quandyfactory/dict2xml

It supports int, float, boolean, string (and unicode), array and dict data types and arbitrary nesting (yay recursion).

I'll post this as an answer once 8 hours have passed.

Comment: There is no un step process for this conversion, but won't be hard to do using json package, and nay XML processing package. At this very site (http://stackoverflow.com/a/191617/212952)  you can find some hints

Comment: In java we have a nice library to convert json to xml https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java/releases

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Nothing came back right away, so I went ahead and wrote a script that solves this problem.

Python already allows you to convert from JSON into a native dict (using `json` or, in versions < 2.6, `simplejson`), so I wrote a library that converts native dicts into an XML string.

https://github.com/quandyfactory/dict2xml

It supports int, float, boolean, string (and unicode), array and dict data types and arbitrary nesting (yay recursion).

Comment: awesome response to actually build (and maintain!) something to resolve a SO question!

Answer (score 18):

If you don't have such a package, you can try:

```
def json2xml(json_obj, line_padding=""):
    result_list = list()

    json_obj_type = type(json_obj)

    if json_obj_type is list:
        for sub_elem in json_obj:
            result_list.append(json2xml(sub_elem, line_padding))

        return "\n".join(result_list)

    if json_obj_type is dict:
        for tag_name in json_obj:
            sub_obj = json_obj[tag_name]
            result_list.append("%s<%s>" % (line_padding, tag_name))
            result_list.append(json2xml(sub_obj, "\t" + line_padding))
            result_list.append("%s</%s>" % (line_padding, tag_name))

        return "\n".join(result_list)

    return "%s%s" % (line_padding, json_obj)
```

For example:

```
s='{"main" : {"aaa" : "10", "bbb" : [1,2,3]}}'
j = json.loads(s)
print(json2xml(j))
```

Result:

```
<main>
        <aaa>
                10
        </aaa>
        <bbb>
                1
                2
                3
        </bbb>
</main>
```

Comment: It is showing an Unresolved reference error on the recursive call  in Python2.7

Comment: given `s = {'person': {'web': {'email': 'boo@baz.com'}, 'address': {'street1': '123 Bar St', 'street2': '', 'state': 'WI', 'zip': 55555, 'city': 'Madison'}}}`.

It is giving `    j = json.loads(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Answer (score 15):

Load it into a dict using json.loads then use anything from this question...

[Serialize Python dictionary to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019895/serialize-python-dictionary-to-xml)

Answer (score 3):

Use `dicttoxml` to convert **JSON** directly to **XML**

**Installation** 
`pip install dicttoxml` 
or 
`easy_install dicttoxml`

```
In [2]: from json import loads

In [3]: from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

In [4]: json_obj = '{"main" : {"aaa" : "10", "bbb" : [1,2,3]}}'

In [5]: xml = dicttoxml(loads(json_obj))

In [6]: print(xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><main type="dict"><aaa type="str">10</aaa><bbb type="list"><item type="int">1</item><item type="int">2</item><item type="int">3</item></bbb></main></root>

In [7]: xml = dicttoxml(loads(json_obj), attr_type=False)

In [8]: print(xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><main><aaa>10</aaa><bbb><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></bbb></main></root>
```

For more information on [dicttoxml](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml)

Comment: this is the same library the user who asked the question wrote..and posted inside the question..........

Answer (score 2):

I found `xmltodict` to be useful. Looks like it was released after some of the posts here. https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/

```
import xmltodict
import json
sample_json = {"note": {"to": "Tove", "from": "Jani", "heading": "Reminder", "body": "Don't forget me this weekend!"}}
#############
#json to xml
#############
json_to_xml = xmltodict.unparse(sample_json)
print(json_to_xml)
#############
#xml to json
#############
x_to_j_dict = xmltodict.parse(json_to_xml)
x_to_j_string = json.dumps(x_to_j_dict)
back_to_json = json.loads(x_to_j_string)
print(back_to_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from json import loads
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

s='{"main" : {"aaa" : "10", "bbb" : [1,2,3]}}'
xml = dicttoxml(loads(s))
```

Or if your data is stored in a pandas `data.frame` as mine often is:

```
df['xml'] = df['json'].apply(lambda s: dicttoxml(json.loads(s))
```