# How To Export ElasticSearch Data Into Xml Format

Tags: xml, elasticsearch

I want to dump the entire ElasticSearch data I have into XML documents. I want to specify the fields that I need and have flexibility on how to organize my XML document. My ElasticSearch repository is not small and I'm thinking about a library to use with Python or any other programming language. How can I do that?
In fact, I'm looking for something like [this project](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump), but instead of jSon, I need XML.

Comment: What kind of flexibility do you need? Can you give a sample XML output that you'd like to see generated?

Comment: I simply need to have control over the XML structure I generate from ElasticSearch indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you'll find something that will do the job without writing some code yourself, e.g. use the tool you mentioned. Most straightforward thing to do is to extract the documents as JSON from ElasticSearch and then transform it into XML, you have plenty of choices to do this depending on the language you want to use. For python as you mentioned it, visit this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988775/convert-json-to-xml-in-python)