# Need to convert webservice data to xml format

Tags: python, unix, curl, urllib2, python-responses

I want to convert the data in webservice url ='http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all' into xml format using Python / Unix. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what code you have tried to get this to work

Comment: In unix i tried, curl -o data.xml "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all".
to save the data in data.xml, but its did not get saved in proper xml format, just the data got fetched.

Comment: And i python I tried,
import requests
resp = requests.get('http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all')
with open('C:/Users/Souvik/PycharmProjects/NewProject/export.xml', 'wb') as foutput:
   foutput.write(resp.content)

The same thing happened, just the data got saved in the format that is in the webservice, not in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are trying to convert is in JSON format.
There's already an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988775/convert-json-to-xml-in-python)