# Marshmallow: How to serialize a dict or an object to XML?

Tags: python, json, xml, marshmallow

I'm new to Python Marshmallow module and quite like it for serialization and de-serialization. I know that after defining a schema, I can easily serialize a dict or an object to JSON format using `schema.dumps` method.

However, I wonder how I could serialize an object or a dict to another format than JSON. For example, sometimes I'd like to serialize an object to XML.

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/130) in Marshmallow's Github repo. It seems its doable by playing with something called `json_module`. However, I can't really follow that thread because I'm quite new to Marshmallow.

Logically, `schema.dumps` seems to be the right method to do that, but from the [documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.dumps), I didn't see a possibility of serializing data to any other format than JSON.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me an example of converting a dict to an XML string.

Edit: Thanks for the answer using `dicttoxml`. It's a good module and indeed it solves my problem. However, isn't the "output formatt control" a built-in feature of `marshmallow`? I though if it were, then the support to controlling output format should be in `schema.dumps` method? Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Marshmallow is essentially *format agnostic*. It outputs a structure of Python dictionaries and lists, that can then be serialised to JSON or to any other format of your choosing.

Comment: So no, Marshmallow does not give you output format control, other than that you can control how object attributes map to key-value pairs in the output dictionaries. The goal is to produce output that is *trivial to serialize*, with whatever serialization method you choose. Usually that's JSON, but can be YAML, XML, CSV or other formats.

Comment: Thanks Martjin. I guess I didn’t understand what the format agnostic really meant when I firstly saw it in marshmallow’s doc. Then what’s marshmallow really good at? For me, what’s left is basically just validation and possibly transformation. So for example, how do you compare marshmallow with cerberus?

Comment: Yes, it is good at exactly that, validation and transformation. It puts data from potentially complex objects (custom classes, etc.) into a structure of lists and dictionaries, and can do the same in reverse.

Comment: I don't know Cerberus, but at first glance it only manages validation. There are more packages in this space, such as [collander](https://pypi.org/project/colander/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52554927/2217801). You could always just post process the json to xml using a library. Try [`dicttoxml`](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/)

```py
import json
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
marshmallow_json_string = schema.dumps
marshmallow_dict = json.loads(marshmallow_json_string)
marshmallow_xml = dicttoxml(marshmallow_dict)
```

Comment: That's a very promising answer. Thanks very much. Still, my gut feeling is that it should have been built into marshmallow, isn't it? Maybe my understanding to marshmallow is wrong but I thought it could control input format, do the transformation and control the output format?

Comment: Possibly I'm not too sure, I don't know how users normally use the package. Either way, I think you are on the right track talking about it in github issues for the repo. Developers who know the purpose of the project there can tell you why they did/didn't include it.

Comment: Have a look [at this issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/737) where someone is taking in json and outputting yaml. I think that's what you might want but for xml.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I think the link you provided really helped me. I’ll set this as the answer. Looking back, what I missed was really how to use the render_module method:)