# JSON to XML File using Python

Tags: python, json, xml

I am trying to convert one big `JSON` file to a `XML` file. Below are the two lines which i took out from a big JSON. I am trying to create a root node for every INVENTORY_SEQ_ID present in this file:

```
[{"INVENTORY_SEQ_ID":4577494,"GROUP_NBR":8605548,"SEQ_NBR":300,"FACILITY_CODE":"OCALADC","COMPANY_CODE":"AMES"},
{"INVENTORY_SEQ_ID":4577495,"GROUP_NBR":8605548,"SEQ_NBR":301,"FACILITY_CODE":"OCALADC","COMPANY_CODE":"AMES"}]
```

I have written below code (I am just a beginner in this field) and it works if there is only one Row in the JSON file. It throw an error if there are more thab one.

```
import json as j
with open("invdata.json") as input_var:
 d=j.load(input_var)
import xml.etree.cElementTree as e
r=e.Element("InvHead")
e.SubElement(r,"INVENTORY_SEQ_ID").text = str(d["INVENTORY_SEQ_ID"])
e.SubElement(r,"GROUP_NBR").text = str(d["GROUP_NBR"])
e.SubElement(r,"SEQ_NBR").text = str(d["SEQ_NBR"])
e.SubElement(r,"FACILITY_CODE").text = d["FACILITY_CODE"]
e.SubElement(r,"COMPANY_CODE").text = d["COMPANY_CODE"]
a=e.ElementTree(r)
a.write("output.xml")
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks
ANmol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON to XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988775/convert-json-to-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

When there is only one object json.load will return a dict, whereas for multiple entries it returns a list of dicts. So you can make your code work if you replace d["INVENTORY_SEQ_ID"] with d[i]["INVENTORY_SEQ_ID"], where i iterates over all your objects.

Instead you can try out this simpler approach

```
from json import load,loads
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

with open("invdata.json") as input_var:
 d=load(input_var)
di = {"InvHead":d}
xm = dicttoxml(di)     #returns xm as <class 'bytes'> object

with open("output.xml", mode='wb') as out:  #opening in write-bytes mode 
    out.write(xm)
```

And the output XML being
[output.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XHZ4.png)

Let me know if this works in your case.
RRP

Answer (score 1):

```
from json import load
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
...
xml = dicttoxml(load(input_var))
```

then save the xml to a file

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt: I needed the dict Keys to become the Tag Names.

```
def to_xml(values):
    result = ""
    # this works only for text and int values.
    # implement your own case for other types.
    if isinstance(values, str) or  isinstance(values, int):
        return values
    elif isinstance(values, dict):
        for key in values:
            result += "<" + key + ">" + str(to_xml(values[key])) + "</" + key + ">"
        return result
```

Output:

```
>>> mydict = {"test":{"foo":"bar","number":1}}
>>> to_xml(mydict)
'<test><foo>bar</foo><number>1</number></test>'
```

If you need it as xml Object you can parse it again:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> minidom.parseString(to_xml(mydict))
<xml.dom.minidom.Document object at 0x7fdc3e9d1be0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `xmltodict` to be useful for this task. See https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/

```
import xmltodict
import json
sample_json = {
    "document":{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hobbies": ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age": 35,
    "children": [
        {
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "age": 6
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "age": 8
        }
    ]}

}
#############
#json to xml
#############
json_to_xml = xmltodict.unparse(sample_json)
print(json_to_xml)
#############
#xmlto json
#############
x_to_j_dict = xmltodict.parse(json_to_xml)
x_to_j_string = json.dumps(x_to_j_dict)
back_to_json = json.loads(x_to_j_string)
print(back_to_json)
```