# Python support to code text according to DTD

Tags: python, dtd

I have a DTD and I have a text where I can identify different structures. I need to code the text accoding to the DTD structure (elements/attributes). I wonder if there is some robust support in Python 2.6 to facilitate this task. Any suggestions about how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you can push your text into a dictionary with the elements/attributes you need, than you can use one of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019895/serialize-python-dictionary-to-xml), to transform the dict to XML. Is this what you need?